# Apple Silicon: port all Homebrew packages under /usr/local/opt/ to /opt/homebrew

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon

I recently purchased a MacBook Pro 13" with the M1 chip and transferred all my data over using a Time Machine backup. Homebrew packages are currently installed in `/usr/local/opt/` but it is my understanding that they should be under `/opt/homebrew` for Apple Silicon Macs.

How can I:

1. Get the list of packages I currently have installed
2. Remove those from `/user/local/opt`
3. Reinstall them under `/opt/homebrew`

I kind of assumed Homebrew would be clever enough to do this automatically but apparently it needs some manual maintenance.

Here's my Homebrew config if it helps:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.7.2
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: dad7dc6a1498b80770d98f2d7cd6fb927c300bbb
Last commit: 3 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 2b1d79d038bffdbfcee93283051d48919a4caf3d
Core tap last commit: 16 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 12.0 build 1200
Git: 2.30.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 11.1-arm64
CLT: 12.3.0.0.1.1607026830
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: false
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

According to https://docs.brew.sh/Installation, `/usr/local` is for Intel binaries, `/opt/homebrew` for ARM. So you may want to reinstall instead of just migrating.

You can dump the list of currently installed packages with `brew bundle dump`. To duplicate your current installation, you'll need to

- run `brew bundle dump` to create a `Brewfile`
- install ARM Homebrew into `/opt/homebrew` by following the instructions in https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

  ```
  cd /opt
  sudo mkdir -p homebrew
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) homebrew
  curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master |\
      tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
  ```
- make sure that the ARM version is at the beginning of your PATH

  ```
  PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Reapply the brew file created in step one

  ```
  hash -d brew
  brew bundle install --file /path/to/Brewfile
  ```
- Optionally run `brew analytics off` to turn off the [tracking/analytics gathering done by Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics)

PS: Some formulae don't seem to work on ARM yet

PPS: `/usr/local/Cellar` and any symlinks from `/usr/local/bin` into it can be removed afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! As I've used the migration assistant to migrate all applications, I had to include `--force` when running `brew bundle install`, but then everything worked fine

Answer (score 17):

Here's the approach I ultimately took.

First, I took note of my installed brew packages:

```bsh
brew list
```

I just kept this as a text file so that I could refer to it later.
I then uninstalled the old version of Homebrew and all its packages:

```bsh
cd ~/Desktop
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh
chmod +x ./uninstall.sh
sudo ./uninstall.sh --path=/usr/local
```

and removed the file once that was done:

```bsh
rm uninstall.sh
```

I then installed Homebrew with M1 support:

```bsh
cd /opt; sudo mkdir homebrew
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

Added the following to my `~/.zshrc` file:

```bsh
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

and sourced it with:

```bsh
source ~/.zshrc
```

I then referred to the list from my first step and began installing the necessary packages one by one :)
Most packages I was using seem to already have ARM support which is awesome!

Comment: Ah. I did‘t think about removing the old installation :-)

Comment: @DaniG2k I am getting the below error brew list

Warning: your HOMEBREW_PREFIX is set to /usr/local but HOMEBREW_CELLAR is set
to /opt/homebrew/Cellar. Your current HOMEBREW_CELLAR location will stop
you being able to use all the binary packages (bottles) Homebrew provides. We
recommend you move your HOMEBREW_CELLAR to /usr/local/Cellar which will get you
access to all bottles."

Comment: Running `sudo ./uninstall.sh --path=/usr/local` actually tries to delete the entire `/usr/local` directory!: `rmdir: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`. Is it safe to run anyway?

Comment: This is an easier option for uninstalling brew, as outlined in the [repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew): `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`.