# List all HEAD formula brew

Tags: macos, homebrew

How do I list all formulas I installed with `brew install --HEAD`. Certain formulas depend of more recent version of a formula and upgrade every time I run `brew upgrade` if a commit has been pushed, I wish to check if the dependency has been satisfied and install normal version.

This was the case where neovim nightly(5.0.0) where it required HEAD version of luarocks (Undocumented in [release page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim)) and recently just works with normal installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [brew: create install script for all installed packages/casks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414225/brew-create-install-script-for-all-installed-packages-casks)

Comment: @fsb `brew bundle` doesn't differenatiate between HEAD and normal release

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This seems like an XY question. What are you trying to do with this once you have a list? There may be an easier way to accomplish the end goal - but it’s ok to just ask this if you can clarify what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: Why do you need to chase most recent commit in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `brew list --versions | grep HEAD`

```
$ brew list --versions | grep HEAD
libimobiledevice HEAD-bfaf1a1
libusbmuxd HEAD-73cb5c1
```