# What programs do I need to reinstall after switching to M1 / Apple Silicon?

Tags: upgrade, apple-silicon

I got a new M1 MBP, and I restored a time machine backup. I found out that electron-based apps (like Slack and Hyper) ran slowly because they were built for an Intel processor, and after deleting them and installing the M1 versions, they ran very quickly. Zoom was the only application to prompt me to update.

What are the other applications that would benefit from me deleting them and installing the M1 version? Is there a way for me to determine which of the ones I have would benefit?

Comment: Apple menu > About this Mac > System Report > Software > Applications. That lists all software on your Mac and what architecture it was built for.

Comment: Also curious about this. I'm a developer and I'm not really sure how to go about this. I did the migration from my old macbook pro, and literally thousands of executables may be "wrong"

Comment: For programs installed by Homebrew, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410829/6414

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything listed as "Intel" on the right of:

Apple menu > About this Mac > System Report > Software > Applications

[image: Applications list]

Note that for some Applications, there might not be a Apple Silicon or Universal option to install, in which case the only option is continuing to use the Intel version (which will run in an emulator).