Can't install libmagic on Mac M1 Pro
I am having significant trouble installing some Python libraries/dependencies for a project I have to work on, specifically with libmagic.
I have tried to install libmagic several ways with no success - installing it through my code editor terminal, installing it through terminal with pip, installing it via Homebrew (including removing Python and existing items and re-installing everything with homebrew).
I consistently receive the following error:
ImportError('failed to find libmagic. Check your installation')
to which I tried to install libmagic with pip. However, I can find a libmagic folder/file after this, but I continue receiving errors, such as a ModuleNotFoundError when I try to run import magic.  I tried various pip install commands with no luck.
I then tried to uninstall everything Python and libmagic related, and reinstall it these Homebrew instructions), and I continued to get errors.  I also tried installing it using Python libmagic for Apple Silicon, and it did not work.
Finally, with the help of a colleague, he used the terminal to determine that there was an architecture error, very similar to this incompatibility error listed in How to solve libmagic.dylib - incompatible architecture error?. I tried following some of the suggestions such as arch -arm64 brew install python, or arch -arm64 brew install libmagic, which had no success.
Does anyone have any idea what I can do here? It is more or less the last dependency I need to install and it's causing so many issues.  I will happily uninstall everything again and start from zero if there is a clear way of having this work. Maybe there is a step I need to do, similar to the arm64 brew python install to help facilitate it installing properly.

This seems to mix a lot of issues, it's also rather difficult to provide ideas as "continue to get errors", "similar to this error" etc. don't give any details about what actually might be wrong. Please add the actual commands run, and the full error output you get by copy/paste the text from Terminal and format as code.

Are you using the Intel version of Homebrew (in /usr/local/bin) or the ARM version (in /opt/homebrew/bin)? How did you install Python, and pip?

In response to your first question, unfortunately this happened about three weeks ago and I sort of gave up at the time and have closed the terminal windows I was using, so I do not have the exact errors anymore which is why I linked to other stack overflow problems with had similar errors - as I was looking at these to try to solve my problem initially.
In response to your second question, this is my output from terminal:
% which brew /usr/local/bin/brew

Did this arm version come out later? I was using the usr/local/bin version of homebrew since the first week of getting my M1 a couple of years ago and did not run into any issues with using it until now.

So you are using the Intel version of Homebrew, and probably quite a mess with Intel and ARM stuff for Python by now. If you would share a lot of details, somebody might be able to propose a low-effort way forward. But it might be easier to start again with installing the ARM64 Homebrew.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410825/apple-silicon-port-all-homebrew-packages-under-usr-local-opt-to-opt-homebrew/410829#410829 for how to migrate from Intel to ARM.

Do you recommend I uninstall homebrew and the reinstall it as the ARM64 version? Or can I run both?

You can run both versions of Homebrew in parallel, if you set PATH depending on your needs. Not sure there is a benefit from that, basically all binaries are available for ARM nowadays. What you can‘t mix is Python libraries, they need to match the architecture of the Python binary used.

After uninstalling libmagic, python, and intel version of homebrew. I re-install homebrew as the ARM64 version, and then for reinstalling python and libmagic should I specify the installation with arch -arm64 brew install python or should the ARM64 version of brew automatically install the correct version i need (ARM64) of python and libmagic?

ARM Homebrew will install the correct version if it is available, even without arch -arm64.
